# MVVM Where to "store" data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvvm

Ok, so i have a question about the the structure of my program, it's left me scratching my head a little.

We've recently switched DB from mysql to mssql, and having done that we also dropped the web services we previously used in favor of direct DB access (to stored procedures ONLY) using application roles.

So, having stripped away the services and supporting interfaces, i'm left with a simple question, where to store data returned from the DB.

What i plan to do currently is have data repositories which handle the calling of the procedures that proform our CRUD work. Would it be logical to store returned data (lists of Model objects such as 'Project', 'Proformas' and 'Shipments')  in these repositories? or should the "storage" of this data be handled elsewhere and the repositories left to handle CRUD only?

Baring mind, that this fetched data is used in a multitude of viewmodels, and that we are attempting to limit the ammount of data connections required, so no working with the live DB directly, as our clients will be running in places with limited internet.

Comment: Have you considered using Entity Framework and LINQ which you could then build your repository around?

Comment: I have looked quickly at the EF, but it seemed a little excessive for this small application, plus from what I've seen using procedures instead of table access adds a level of complexity to this, and having zero experience with EF's i shied away from them.

Comment: I'd try to solve this *in* the repository or a dependency of it. If you just want to minimize the amount of calls to the DB, why not just implement some caching in the repo? The calling code (let alone the GUI) would never know the difference.

Comment: may Table-valued parameters will be good .[TVP](http://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/)